# Javascript Mocha Tests - Testing function expressions inside function expressions

Tags: javascript, function, testing, mocha.js, chai

I haven't used Mocha before, so I am a real novice when it comes to testing. However, I wanted to know if it's possible to test a function expression inside of a function expression? I know there are other posts on how you cannot access function expressions inside function declarations and so on.

So, is it possible to access function expressions inside function expressions and test with Mocha? For example, I have the following code:

```
var masterFunction = function() {

       var siGogglin = functionDeclaration(putSomethingHere);

       function functionDeclaration(code) {
           var yoyo = [];

           //some stuff I don't want you to see 

           return yoyo;
       };
};
```

Is it possible to test the function `functionDeclaration` from the variable `siGogglin` within `masterFunction`? If so, could you give me an example of how it could be done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer would be no because you essentially created a private function within masterFunction which  should have no access outside of the masterFunction scope unless you add a getter method to the prototype.

Comment: That's what I thought but I wanted to ask anyway. Thanks.